# Add a twig variable to a certain href url menu item when it is being created

Tags: theming, 8

I have a Drupal 8 install that I am trying to add a variable to a href  URL when it equals #blog but I can't get it to work. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

This is my menu template file:

```
{{item.url}} 
{% if item.url == '#blog'  %} 
    <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="dropdown-toggle" style="color:red;" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ item.title }} <span class="caret"></span> /Tksksks iss</a>
{% else %}
    {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: what you want to do? if url == #blog create <a  else render it simply? what is your problem, you can't add '#blog'?

Comment: just guessing, maybe try `{% if item.url[0] == '#blog'  %} `

Comment: Nope that did not work

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this and have a late answer for you.  Your twig template's if statement does not work because your string comparison is against the Drupal Core URL object. You can, however, create a variable in twig and use that for your comparison.

```
{% set menuUri %}{{ item.url }}{% endset %}
{% if menuUri == '#blog'  %} 
    <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="dropdown-toggle" style="color:red;" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ item.title }} <span class="caret"></span> /Tksksks iss</a>
{% else %}
    {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
{% endif %}
```

This will let your comparison to the URL "#blog" work just fine.